# android: Custom editable form

Tags: android, layout

How can I create following layouts:

[image]

And

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using an custom listview..To know how to build custom listview refer this tutorials:

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html